# Difference between two statements

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Is there any difference between:

```
this->textBox1->Text = this->textBox1->Text + ("2");
```

and this:

```
this->textBox1->Text = this->textBox1->Text + "2";
```

or it is just a syntactic sugar?

Comment: The overloaded operator is syntactic sugar. Adding/removing parentheses is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the exactly same, so no difference as far as the result goes.
The compiler first will evaluate whats in the brackets, since it is just ("2"), it will result in "2", therefore the same as your second code.